# Kernel module and its kernel version

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

What decides the kernel version of a module built by us? I mean I want to know whether we can decide by our own that against which kernel version we can build our kernel module (`vermagic` version magic).

Answer (score 1):

So what you want is to build a module without recompiling the kernel, if I understand correctly. The version conflict issue can be solved in the Makefile of your module, by setting EXTRAVERSION to the desired value. You can find what that is by running `modinfo $module`, where $module is a module from the running kernel, e.g., on my laptop, `/lib/modules/5.4.0-3-amd64/kernel/sound/ac97_bus.ko` . For reference, consult this : https://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x380.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and accurately understanding my question